# How can the master figure out if an I2C slave is busy without interrupting time-sensitive code on the slave?

Tags: arduino, embedded, microcontroller, i2c

So I have a device set as the I2C master, and the rest of the devices on the bus are set as slaves. The master sends a command to each slave, and the slave executes this task (running motors, etc, important time-sensitive code). I would like to be able to know when the slave is finished executing its task. The only way I can see to do this is to constantly have the master poll the slave, but this creates an issue, because every time the master polls the slave, it triggers and i2c interrupt on the slave and quits running the motor code for a short amount of time.

Is there anyway to solve this? I was thinking of setting all devices as a master, so then when each device finishes it task, it can send the data over saying that it is done, without the need for polling. The issue with this is I'm worried about data collision over the bus with devices possibly trying to talk at the same time.

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Comment: How do you know when a motor has "finished its task"? Let's assume that the I2C message did not stop the motor running, how would you know it had finished its task? Most I2C devices cannot be set as masters, I don't see that as being a legitimate method. We need much more detailed description of your set-up and how each of these peripherals  completes its function.

Comment: Off the top of my head: start master init all slaves with a time slot where they can send info update.

Comment: do your system engineering...

Comment: the answer is extremely specific to the slave, you have to investigate that, call their tech support, read their docs, it should have a rough idea how long a task takes and you at least hold off that long.  or you can do it experimentally, overshoot by a lot where you never see it busy, and shorten that time until you do, repeat for your expected use cases, and determine the worst case.  (and does that fit into your system engineering design, does that fit with the documenation/information from the slave vendor, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Let the slave disable its I2C interface while it's running a time-critical task, and re-enable afterwards. Then, the master can poll as often as it wants to, it would get no ACK from the busy slave, and the slave won't get any interrupts either.